# NextJS use-immer, Array.map() missing property on type

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have an application that loads some GPX data into an object called TrackData. TrackData comes from some static JSON, and resembles:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1ffc6ae5-76b0-44e9-8d26-e190ff9404e8",
        "title": "First Park",
        "coords": { *snip* }
    },
    { .. }
]
```

I have a class, called Track, that represents more information about the same track:

```js
// Track.ts
export default class Track {
    readonly id: string //GUID
    readonly title: string // Name of the track, as seen on the website
    readonly coords: object

    // These properties get defined from the database, so they may not exist.
    condition?: string
    notes: string = ""
    lastgroomed?: Date | null | undefined // Groom date/time
    groomed?: boolean = false // If it's been groomed.

    constructor(id: string, title: string, coords: object) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.coords = coords;
    }

    getGroomDateFriendly(): string {
        if (this.lastgroomed !== null) {
            const formatted = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("default", {
                weekday: 'short',
                month: 'short',
                day: 'numeric',
                year: 'numeric',
                timeZone: 'America/Edmonton',
            }).format(this.lastgroomed)
            return formatted
        }
        return "N/A"
    }
}
```

In the tsx for the page, I set the missing values to some defaults using `use-immer`:

```js
    const [Tracks, setTrack] = useImmer<Track[]>(TrackData?.map(x => (
        {
            ...x,
            lastgroomed: currentTimeStamp,
            condition: "ok",
            coords: {},
            groomed: false,
            notes: "",
            __customNotes: false,
            __customCondition: false,
            __customLastGroomed: false,
        }
    )));
```

This is generating a typescript warning `Property 'getGroomDateFriendly' is missing in type '{ lastgroomed: Date; condition: string; coords: {}; groomed: false; notes: string; __customNotes: false; __customCondition: false; __customLastGroomed: false; id: string; title: string; }' but required in type 'Track'`.

I thought Array.map() created a copy of a given object, but I think I understand that since I'm not iterating an array of Track's, there's now a type mis-match.

So I thought I would loop through TrackData, create new Track's for each TrackData, add the newly created objects to an array, and use that as my initial state for useImmer:

```js
  const TrackDataArray: Track[] = new Array();
    TrackData.forEach(function (element) {
        var newTrack = new Track(element.id, element.title, element.coords)
        newTrack.lastgroomed = currentTimeStamp;
        newTrack.condition = "ok";
        newTrack.groomed = false;
        newTrack.notes = "";
        newTrack.__customCondition = false;
        newTrack.__customLastGroomed = false;
        newTrack.__customNotes = false;
        TrackDataArray.push(newTrack);
    })
    const [Tracks, setTrack] = useImmer<Track[]>(TrackDataArray);
```

This successfully removed the TypeScript warnings, but made all the components that reference properties in these objects read-only. Stepping through debugging, I can see the data being updated in Tracks, but not reflected on the page.

The data is shown on the page like the following:

```html
{Tracks.map((ThisTrack) => (
    <div key={ThisTrack.id} className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
        <div className={`p-2 md:p-4 ${ThisTrack.groomed ? 'bg-green-100' : ''}`}>
            <Switch checked={ThisTrack.groomed} label={ThisTrack.title} className="font-bold" onChange={() => {
                setTrack((draft) => {
                    const track = ensure(draft.find((track) => track.id === ThisTrack.id))
                    track.groomed = !track.groomed
                })
            }}
...etc...
            />
```

Help me understand what's going on here, in either case, so I can learn how to fix it.

Thanks.